How to Provide Entire Web Content from WKWebView to iOS Screenshot Editor?
I'm developing an iOS app that uses a tab bar interface, with each tab displaying content in a WKWebView. I want to enable users to capture the entire web content using the default iOS screenshot editor, similar to how Safari handles full-page screenshots (see example below).

I've explored a few options:

ScreenCaptureKit: It seems promising, but unfortunately, it is a macOS-only SDK.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions: This allows saving images, but it does not integrate with the default system screenshot editor.

Is there a way to programmatically provide the full web content from a WKWebView to the iOS screenshot editor when a user takes a screenshot? I would prefer to leverage the built-in screenshot editing tools provided by iOS.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

I dont think they make those tools public
